# Why do native English speakers analyze "a lot" as one word?

Tags: words, word-formation

At least in the US, many, maybe most, native English speakers spell "a lot" as one word until taught otherwise. Why is this such a common phenomenon?

There are several pieces of (non-written based) evidence that it should be analyzed as two words, including most significantly that it can be interrupted by "whole," or, less commonly, "great, (n) awful." The same phenomenon doesn't seem to happen for parallel constructions, e.g. nobody seems to analyze "abunch, afew" as single words.

Comment: It is a life view of language change. BTW, you probably love the alot, see http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.de/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html

Comment: _A lot_ has gone farther toward fusion than _a bunch_. We still use the word _bunch_, but when was the last time you heard _lot_ used to mean 'a large number' without _a_ in front of it? The same thing happened -- in one direction or another -- to _nickname, adder_, and _orange_.

Comment: @jlawler "the lot" is still very common.

Comment: @curiousdannii: it seems to me that has a different meaning: "the lot" means "all".

Comment: Right. Different idiom. But frozen forms can get locked if there isn't ever any reason to separate the words; kids won't learn them as separated. (though, actually, I think _lot of_ is far frozener than _alot_ is. There's an eye spelling _lotta_ already, and it occurs without _a_ in some contexts.)

Comment: *Lotta* is eye dialect representing the ordinary pronunciation of *lot of*. The article in *a whole lot of* is often dropped at the beginning of spoken sentences--*Whole Lotta Shakin Goin On* wrote Williams and Hall in 1955; I imagine Prof. Lawler will confirm that this is attributable to conversational deletion.

Comment: "Another" is written together even though we can say "a whole other" or "a whole nother."

Comment: Here's a relevant question on ELU; I hope the answers are somewhat useful: [Why is writing “alot” such a common mistake?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21716/why-is-writing-alot-such-a-common-mistake)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem starts not with the noun phrase "a lot of ...", but with the adverbial phrase "a lot [of the time]" (meaning 'often').  It is unusual for an adverbial phrase to begin with a determiner (article), so the learner assumes that 'a lot' is one word ('alot'), since the temporal cue 'of the time' is often elided.

Answer (score 1):

'lot' is a common noun and the plural is 'lots' - both are commonly used in auctions, but also to refer to indeterminate quantities of something. Similar to 
'a bunch of flowers', 'a gaggle of geese' or 'a cup of tea'. Spelling is arbitrary say the knowing linguists!